# Design entity model by Inheritance versus Association for Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-6, table-per-type

I'm using EF 6 Code First, and I'm facing a design decision:

## The entity model

I have an abstract entity which is realized by several concrete ones, each of which add several attributes to the entity. I have polymorphic associations (base class has several related entities), so when mapping this in EF, it makes a clear case for TPT inheritance. (More info here for readers: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)

## The issue with TPT design

What I'm concerned about, is that I have several cases where I only need to process data on the base class. To be specific, I have several scheduled batch processes that need to load the entities and perform calculations and updates.

TPT inheritance will cause performing JOIN on all sub-type tables, which is unnecessary for my case.

## Second design option

My second option is to create separate concrete entities for parent and child types, and forget about the inheritance altogether.

From the SQL point of view, these designs will be equivalent. From the object-oriented point of view, this option is **less correct**. Plus, reaching child entities from the parent is not *clean* enough.

## When to use which design?

Personally, I'm leaning toward the second design (associations) because most of my cases would be easier and simpler. (Less logic handled by the ORM tool means more control and simplicity).

**My question is** when to use which design.